# nginx redirect matching servname and location in multi name vhost

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I am using nginx/1.4.6 Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.
I have a SSL vhost that looks begins with the follwing

```
server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        server_name example1.com example2.com example3.com;
```

How would you write a redirect so that if anything matches example2.com/location* gets re-written to example2.com/page.html?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are three variables that can help you identify the name of the server that accepted a request: `$host`, `$http_host` and `$server_name`.

To perform the external redirect indicated in your question, you could use:

```
location /location {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/page.html;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html) for details.